# Lint prefers erase() method on std:string rather than clear()

Tags: c++, string, std

Using Lint it repeatedly objects to using clear on a std string and wants to suggest using the erase method with no parameters.

Looking at the documentation both with do what I desire and that is to resize the string to zero elements so that the string is empty with no elements. I do not want to delete the string at this point simply remove all members from it.

My question is what is the difference between the two methods and does anyone know the reason I SHOULD be using erase over the clear method ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot see a single reason for this. Quite the opposite: I actually had to look into the reference to see whether `erase()` can be called without arguments. `erase()` is used to remove *some specified characters* from the string. `clear()` is used to remove the entire contents of the string (but not its capacity).

The general programming rule is "write what you mean." If you want to clear the entire string, use the function for it: `clear()`.

Furthermore, in the general case, `erase()` has more work to do—it must check that the index is in range, and throw an exception if not. `clear()` is guaranteed non-throwing. Clever optimisers might make them identical, but I would consider using `erase()` instead of `clear()` "premature" pessimisation.

Comment: Yes. You should only pessimize your code *after* you've profiled it and proved it's too efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I too prescribe to the "write what you mean." So it's frustrating that it would do this. It's mainly a legacy system that we HAVE to work with so we will be making a combination of ignores and cleaning of parts of the code.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like Lint is simply being over-picky about things. In fact, in C++11, `clear` is defined as `noexcept`, while `erase` only has a strong exception guarantee. `clear` has clearer semantics as well; with `erase`, whoever is reading the code must then check what range is being erased; there is no ambiguity with `clear`.

I would ignore/disable the Lint warning in this case.

Comment: Thanks it's mainly in the legacy part of the system so we are going to make some exceptions.